# Load specific step in One Page Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, onepage-checkout

A link is sent to a customer to complete the payment on payment pending.
So the link redirects the customer to the one page checkout.
Where all the details are filled in through the quote of the order.

**Now I have to load directly to the Review Step.**

I tried doing through javascript but it doesnot work all the time.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  billing.save(); 
  setTimeout(function(){shipping.save();},3000);
  setTimeout(function(){
    shippingMethod.save();
  },5000);
  setTimeout(function(){
       var method=document.getElementById('gwl_method_code').value;
      document.getElementById('p_method_'+method).checked="true";
  },7000);
   setTimeout(function(){payment.save();},7200);

},2000);
```

Please Help with this